# Flash S1 ep15 how does Flash return to his original timeline? Is it even possible?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

It is said: “The Flash” teased fans with Iris finding out that her best friend is the Scarlet Speedster in the erased timeline.

So does it mean that the original timeline is erased?

Can the Flash go back to the original timeline or does he have to live in a new timeline?